# Fetch data from form and display in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to modify posts app from a django tutorial-  https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Advancing-the-Blog/tree/master/src/posts

I'm creating a new field 'userc' in a forms.py:

```
   userc = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True))
```

I've tried various methods but I'm unable to display the selected user in the template.

What should I add in views.py?

**Edit:**
I've tried {{ obj.userc }}, {{ instance.userc }} to display the selected user in templates.

views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone

from comments.forms import CommentForm
from comments.models import Comment
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)





def abc(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
      #Get the posted form
      form = PostForm(request.POST)

      if form.is_valid():
         userc = form.cleaned_data['userc']
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {"selected_user" : userc})

















def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)




    initial_data = {
            "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
            "object_id": instance.id
    }
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent_id"))
        except:
            parent_id = None

        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                parent_obj = parent_qs.first()


        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data,
                            parent = parent_obj,
                        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())


    comments = instance.comments
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active() #.order_by("-timestamp")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)





def post_update(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "<a href='#'>Item</a> Saved", extra_tags='html_safe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)



def post_delete(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:list")
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer. What do you want to do with that field? What output are you expecting? What does the rest of your view look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is the rest of the app- https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Advancing-the-Blog/tree/master/src/posts . I've added a new field 'userc' to forms.py which allows you to select a user. I want this selected user to be displayed in the template.

Comment: That's still not nearly enough detail. *Which* view? And more importantly, what did you try in your "various methods" and what happened?

Comment: I don't understand why it is proving so difficult for you to **show the actual view**. Without seeing that view so we can see what you are actually doing and what objects are being sent to the context, it is impossible to help.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated!

Comment: @uitwaa can you explain better what is your goal and how I can help to better answer your question? I've got plenty of experience in what you've been going through

Comment: @tiagoperes I've a field 'userc' in forms.py. It allows you to select one of the staff members. Now I want to display/print the selected member in one of my template.

Comment: what do you mean with "I've a field 'userc'"? Don't find anything with that name in forms.py...  https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Advancing-the-Blog/blob/master/src/posts/forms.py

Comment: @tiagoperes I've added this line-  userc = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)) in the existing forms.py of this app- https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Advancing-the-Blog/tree/master/src/posts . I mean I've modified it on my own.

Comment: why did you do that?

Comment: Because I wanted to select one of the staff member?

Comment: I'm having troubles visualizing what you need. Do you want to display the name of a person that's logged on in a page next to a form or you want to use a form, write there a name and then display that name in the page or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149052/discussion-between-uitwaa-and-tiago-peres).

Comment: Is userc field will be a select field are option being shown? When you selected the user from dropdown list. I assume you want to show the selected user in some part of the template. But the selected user is not provided by the django context. So you need to use javascript to display the user at some other place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have so far in `forms.py` and `views.py` is good. However, to display `userc` in the `post_detail.html` and `post_list.html` templates, you'll need to save the field to the database when the form is submitted.

One way to do this is add a `userc` field to the `Post` model:

1. Add `userc = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='userc', default=1)` to the `Post` class in `posts/models.py`
2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations posts` and then `python manage.py migrate` on the command line (making sure you're in the `src` directory first)

Now, in the `post_detail.html` template, you can add `{{ instance.userc }}` to display the selected user.

**note**: `related_name='userc'` is required as `Post` already has a foreign key to the user model.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the instance as a context variable.

`context = {
"form": form,
"instance": instance
}`

Set `instance = None` before to make it work if `request.method` is not POST. Templates can access only the variables that are passed as context in the view. So passing instance in the context will let you use `{{instance.userc}}`.

CodingforEntrepenuers is an excellent tutorial, but I would recommend to follow along more closely and get your fundamentals right.